# Execute a VSTS query and get all its details using API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I created a VSTS query under a folder **shared**. But when I try to list all queries under my domain nothing in that folder is showing. That folder name is showing in that JSON response. But real queries under that folder is not showing.

This is the way I tried to list all queries

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{projectid}/_apis/wit/queries?api-version=4.1
```

But its just listing the top folders. I need to list all queries under that project

Next and major issue is once I have an API id and on executing its only giving me the workitem ID and url. I am not getting any details such as its task or bug or that specific information

This is the way I tried

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/wit/wiql/{wiqlid}?api-version=5.0&$expand=all
```

Please help me how to solve these two troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try `depth` parameter?

> In the folder of queries, return child queries and folders to this depth.

If you do this you shloud get queries in children collection.

```
https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/DevOps Manual/_apis/wit/queries?$expand=all&$depth=2&api-version=5.1
```

If you queries are in subfolder this may help you.

When I run wiql I got this:

```
https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/DevOps Manual/DevOps Manual Team/_apis/wit/wiql/91dad662-7104-4882-b28f-945c152fc4ee?api-version=5.1
```

```
{
    "queryType": "flat",
    "queryResultType": "workItem",
    "asOf": "2020-05-15T10:12:01.163Z",
    "columns": [
        {
            "referenceName": "System.Id",
            "name": "ID",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/wit/fields/System.Id"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.WorkItemType",
            "name": "Work Item Type",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/wit/fields/System.WorkItemType"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.Title",
            "name": "Title",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/wit/fields/System.Title"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.State",
            "name": "State",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/wit/fields/System.State"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.AreaPath",
            "name": "Area Path",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/wit/fields/System.AreaPath"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.IterationPath",
            "name": "Iteration Path",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/wit/fields/System.IterationPath"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.Tags",
            "name": "Tags",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/wit/fields/System.Tags"
        }
    ],
    "sortColumns": [
        {
            "field": {
                "referenceName": "System.ChangedDate",
                "name": "Changed Date",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/wit/fields/System.ChangedDate"
            },
            "descending": true
        }
    ],
    "workItems": []
}
```

And this is a wiql query run behind:

```sql
select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] 
from Workitems 
where [System.TeamProject] = @project and [System.WorkItemType] <> '' and [System.State] <> ''
```

Is this what you want to get?

**EDIT**

You are nissing team here

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/wit/wiql/{wiqlid}?api-version=5.0&$expand=all
```

Please add `team` after `proj`

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/{wiqlid}?api-version=5.0&$expand=all
```

{team}

Comment: Depth parameter help me to get that subfolder queries. Thanks a lot. But the second problem not solved. Work Item Type is not getting from query